# Game Development in Python, ruby or LUA?

Tags: python, ruby, lua, game-engine

I have experience in game development in some game engines in Action Script 3 and C++.
However, I would like to improve the productivity and so I want to develop a new project in Python, ruby or LUA.
Would it be a good idea? If yes, which one would you suggest? and what is the killer game development tool set or engine?

Comment: Unity has some support for Lua also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're any good, go with [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).
It's a cross-platform Python version independent hook against OpenGL with outstanding performance. It's a bit tricky but it does the job better than anything else out there in the Python world.

If you're a beginner, i'd go with [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/).
It's a bit taxing on the system but with a modern computer that isn't a issue.. also, it got pre-packaged API's for game development (hence the name) :)

A "official" list of Python gaming/graphic engines:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGames

Some good ones:

- Panda3D
- Pyglet
- PyGame
- Blender3D

## Example Pyglet code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyglet
from time import time, sleep

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, refreshrate):
        super(Window, self).__init__(vsync = False)
        self.frames = 0
        self.framerate = pyglet.text.Label(text='Unknown', font_name='Verdana', font_size=8, x=10, y=10, color=(255,255,255,255))
        self.last = time()
        self.alive = 1
        self.refreshrate = refreshrate
        self.click = None
        self.drag = False

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        self.click = x,y

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        if self.click:
            self.drag = True
            print 'Drag offset:',(dx,dy)

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        if not self.drag and self.click:
            print 'You clicked here', self.click, 'Relese point:',(x,y)
        else:
            print 'You draged from', self.click, 'to:',(x,y)
        self.click = None
        self.drag = False

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        if time() - self.last >= 1:
            self.framerate.text = str(self.frames)
            self.frames = 0
            self.last = time()
        else:
            self.frames += 1
        self.framerate.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.render()
            # ----> Note: <----
            #  Without self.dispatc_events() the screen will freeze
            #  due to the fact that i don't call pyglet.app.run(),
            #  because i like to have the control when and what locks
            #  the application, since pyglet.app.run() is a locking call.
            event = self.dispatch_events()
            sleep(1.0/self.refreshrate)

win = Window(23) # set the fps
win.run()
```

---

## Note on Pyglet with Python 3.X:

You'll have to download the **1.2alpha1** otherwise it will complain about you not having Python3.X installed :)